# C++ How to get a number after specific string in file

Tags: c++

I am beggining "programmer" learning c++ ( and SDL ) on my own.
Last few hours I've been looking everywhere for such example but i couldn't find any. ( or I didn't understand explanation )
I need to find a specific string ( "width = " ) in a .txt file and get the number after it.

File content:

```
[header]  
width = 100  
height = 100
```

Comment: Post what you have done until now.

Comment: I have been changing code all the time so it had no point posting it here, sorry. adres's code works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    ss >> line; 
    if(line != "width") continue;
    ss >> line; //=
    ss >> line; //100
    std::cout << line;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `find_*` and `substr`?

Comment: @Nawaz I realized after I wrote it, it would be better to have it do a full string comparison.

Comment: This works! Thank you very much. Sadly I don't know why but I'll get to it. ^^

Comment: @user3284347 No thanks needed. Just check this as the answer to help others.